# removing .php from my site URL's using htaccess, now wordpress doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My sites been using the below code to remove the .PHP from the end of the URL's

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
```

I've now installed WordPress in /clients/ on the folder but it's not working as it's rewriting WordPress as well which i don't want it to do but I'm not sure how to fix the above code to stop it happening in the sup folder.

Thanks

Full .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Or, compress certain file types by extension:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

Answer (score 0):

In the /clients/ folder add an .htaccess file with the following:-

```
RewriteEngine off
```

in it. This turns off mod_rewrite for that folder and it's children.

Voila